# Parallax script (Injected into Enjin with code injection) Can't click buttons

Tags: javascript, css, z-index, parallax, code-injection

So after a million tries I finally have my Parallax website background up and running on http://teeria.net/ Now the only issue is (as you can see for yourself) is that whenever you enter the website you can't click any button and once you click and grab anywhere you will see that you're grabbing one of the images seen in the Parallax effect.

So I assumed that the the Parallax is above the website layer which I can't edit directly which is the reason why I injected the code with Code Injection.

Now I have tried setting z-index: -1 and -9999; in the CSS, but sadly didn't change anything. So i assumed it had to do with the code and I found a line which could make this possible which is: object.style.zIndex="-1"

Sadly I barrely know anything about JS and I was wondering if someone could possibly help me solve this problem as I am so close to making it work, If you need the code I can always upload it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see no parallax effects and the buttons work fine.

Comment: I was editing, sorry could you please try again? Because it's enabled now.

Comment: Sure thing, I wrote you a simple fix, but I'm not a fan of the whole implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the simplest fixes is to add a pointer-events rule to your parallax wrapper:

```
.css3-wrapper {
    pointer-events: none
}
```

What is does is basically telling that the wrapper should respond to no mouse/touch events (causing the clicks/taps to "go through"), which is fine in your case since the parallax is driven by JS.

Comment: Okay so I have edited my .css3-wrapper and as you can see (even if you scroll down) that the parallax is a bit messed up, you can click on the upper menu buttons but not on the youtube button.

Comment: Hm, I can click on all youtube buttons, even the footer link you have at the bottom.

Comment: EDIT: the background was messed up (probably cache) but it seems to work now?

Comment: Yeah, it actually looks exactly the same with and without the pointer-events set.

Comment: Even though when you click on "HOME" and go to the server page you can't see the Logo (Which is the big transparent block above). hmm i could try adding a transparent section

Comment: I never saw the logo, even in your original version, what element is it?

Comment: It's a build in element into Enjin, the logo on top is supposed to look like this: http://oi62.tinypic.com/2lmqgjn.jpg But I have already added an transparent window to it as you can see on the main page now